# lucene title/content searching

Tags: java, lucene

I'm storing my lucene docs like so:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("contents", "Homer January, Lenny February"));
doc.add(new TextField("title", "2017 on call schedule.xls", Field.Store.YES));

Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("contents", "Carl January, Frank February"));
doc.add(new TextField("title", "2018 on call schedule.xls", Field.Store.YES));
```

I can get a hit if I search for the exact title, or for like

```
2017
```

but no hits if i try things like

```
call
on call
xls
```

I've tried simple things like

```
 Query query1 = new QueryParser("title", analyzer).parse("on call");
```

and more complicated ideas like

```
Builder bb = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
for(String chunk : "on call".split(" ")){
    bb.add(new TermQuery(new Term("title", chunk)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = bb.build();
```

maybe I'm storing my Docs wrong?

I'm using the `StandardAnalyzer` on search & insert.

Seems like I'm missing something quite fundamental here.. Anyone have any tips please?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Whatever issue you are running into, what you have provided here does not appear to reproduce it. See here: https://pastebin.com/B19JuCiL

Comment: That is a nice tidy demo. I agree with your findings, I'll try to tighten this down into something reproducible.. stay tuned everyone

Comment: Seems I'm having issues with both case-sensitivity & the period.

Comment: what a puzzle, here's to tomorrow

Comment: why do you think a search for 'schedule' returns no hits? anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, its always a good idea to visualize your terms before running your search. Below is image from Luke tool.

[image]

That simply indicates that there is no term with `schedule` but `schedule.xls`.

I am using Lucene 6.6.6 and had to modify your code to ,

```
Document doc = new Document();

        doc.add(new TextField("contents", "Homer January, Lenny February",Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("title", "2017 on call schedule.xls", Store.YES));

        iwriter.addDocument(doc);

        doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("contents", "Carl January, Frank February",Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("title", "2018 on call schedule.xls", Store.YES));

        iwriter.addDocument(doc);

        iwriter.commit();
```

**Now for searching**

Your query parser is basically producing a query - `title:schedule` that means an exact search ( without wild cards ) on field `title` and since there are no such terms , you find zero hits.

Modifying your query to - `Query query1 = new QueryParser("title", analyzer).parse("schedule*");` will get you two hits.

So as a best practice, before searching , always try to have a look & visualize  your indexed data.

Comment: I will sanitize the titles to remove punctuation. I read - a period that's not followed by whitespace is considered part of a token.

I like this behavior, though not for file names. 

I tried using Luke but it always says 'Index is locked. Try Force unlock when opening', and then 'read past EOF'